# How can I import externally changed files into a TFS project?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a project under source control in TFS.  A developer has made some changes external to our network TFS installation and I have the files on flash drive.  When I copy the new files into my local TFS folder and try to push up the changes TFS informs me there are no changes. When I do a compare I do see that there are changes.

What is the best way to get these changes back into TFS.  Excuse my ignorance I have primarily worked with the Work/Test tabs in TFS.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the files into your local TFS mapped folder and than add into TFS through right clicking Source Control explorer and selecting Add Items to Folder. .[image]

Comment: Thanks that works but it is not letting me push all the changes up. I see the changes to the .cs files when I do the compare but TFS is not uploading the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local workspace instead of a server workspace. Local workspaces are based on the file system and do not require you to check out files before you see that they're changed.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your input, we are using hosted TFS and I don't see an option to create a local workspace - server is the only option and the "Location" field is greyed out.